# CRT debug и release - возможна ли совместная их работа

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Библиотека собрана так, что для ее работы требуются CRT (VC++ 2009) конфигураций debug и release одновременно. Это стало следствием линковки ее с модулями, собранными с разными конфигурациями CRT.

Поясните, пожалуйста, в чем именно заключается проблема при работе в такой конфигурации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть некоторый **`rule of thumb`** - не использовать совместо билды, собранные под `Debug runtime` и `Release runtime`.

---

В общем случае, это, вероятно, может никак не повлиять на финальную работу продукта, разве что только потребуется **2 различных рантайма**. Но в некоторых нетривиальных ситуациях *все может оказаться достаточно плохо.*

Поскольку билд в конфигурации `Debug` подразумевает линковку к дебажным версиям системных функций *(а это и аллокация памяти, и проверка валидности итераторов, и общий `wrapper` для вызова функции `main`, ...)*, то смешивание вызовов этих функций из `msvcrtd` и `msvcrt` вполне как может приводить к `undefined behavior`.

Плюс, еще один вполне очевидный недостаток - вызов дебажных версий системных функций в `hotspot'ах` **вполне может угрохать всю производительность целого приложения.**